# PHPunit test not following through after ZF form validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm brand new to phpunit testing. Can anyone help me on how to test the lines below in the image.

[image: Img example]

So far my test is:

```
public function testCanSendEmail()
{
    $formData = array(
        'subject'   => 'test subject',
        'email'     => 'test@mail.com',
        'message'   => 'test message',
        'name'      => 'test name');

    $this->request
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setPost($formData);
    $this->dispatch('/contact');
    $this->assertAction('win');
```

I was under the impression that if the validation succeeded it would follow through the whole action? Can anyone please explain what is happening here, and also what a correct test would be for such an action.

Comment: Can you put after $this->dispatch('/contact'); the following var_dump($this->getResponse()->getBody()); this will return the html body and maybe you will be able to see if any validation error messages are being shown.

Comment: +1 @Gordon for the interesting link. And good luck in the Moderator election. ;-)

Comment: @David thanks, though I guess it's safe to say that I wont get past the primary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious explanation is that `$form->isValid` returns `FALSE`.

The [coverage report](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) shows that the `if` block for a valid form never got executed. Instead, the else block was executed. The thing you need to find out is why and eliminate the cause. Use a Debugger and step through the execution flow to see what happens at runtime.

As an alternative, you can stub the contact form to return `TRUE`. Because the form is hardcoded into the controller action, have a look at http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html on how to do that.

Yet another alternative: make the code to send the contact form into a Service Layer to allow testing this without having to make an actual request.